# Fonts on launch screen are different than main storyboard

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

On Xcode 6.3.1 I created a launch screen for my app with the same initial ViewController for the app.

The problem is that when the app is launched all the fonts have a slightly different size.

I'm using the Headline and Caption 1 text styles on the labels.

There are some pictures below to make the problem clearer.

Thanks!

Launch screen:

[image: Launch screen]

Main Storyboard initial view controller:

[image: Main Storyboard View Controller]

The difference is noticeable when superimposing both images:

[image: Superimposed images]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can't use custom fonts on the Launch screen.
Only standard system fonts.

System will automatically replace your custom font to system during runtime.

Comment: Ok, I didn't realize the default Font Styles also counted as custom fonts. Anyway I managed to make the fonts look the same by incrementing one point in the size of the System font in the launch screen.

Comment: I also had same problem in previous project, and didn't find solution except capture custom font label as image, and put it to Launch screen and other screen

Comment: The same for me here. It looks like the custom fonts are not loaded at the runtime of launchscreen. Curiously, the image files are loaded.

Answer (score 2):

It's because during launch screen is being shown, the custom fonts in your app aren't loaded yet. I would advise you to use an image on the launch screen if you really need to use custom fonts.